# Windows 10 constantly refreshing

Tags: windows-10, dell-latitude

Today, I installed Windows 10 build 10240 with a clean install; it was NOT an upgrade. The issue is that it is constantly refreshing, no matter what program you are using. The symptom is that the processor appears to lock up while in the middle of typing a sentence, which takes over the cursor momentarily. What I have done:

1. Removed unnecessary startup items and services that might be pulling the processor
2. Removed OneDrive from the tray, as it was not yet connected
3. Cleared system tray notifications
4. Device Manager shows all device drivers are working properly
5. DXDIAG shows Display, Sound, and Input drivers with no problems
6. Reinstalled input driver from Dell support site
7. Windows update has been run and set to Automatic
8. Tested on Wireless Internet versus Ethernet

Observation: Wireless does not appear to have this problem.

Comment: Have you check whether all your device driver up to date? have you updates your windows? (go to settings and click updates).

Comment: Just go to microsoft and get the retail version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Task Manager, processor utilization was high. The largest contributor to this was an "antimalware service executable", i.e. Windows Defender. I prefer not to use or rely on Windows Defender as I have another program that I use. At the time, I was on Ethernet. I did the following:

1. Press the Windows key and search `administrative tools`.
2. Select `Administrative Tools` and select `Task Scheduler`.
3. Navigate to `/Library/Microsoft/Windows/Windows defender`
4. Right-click on the properties for each scan component
5. Click the `Conditions` tab
6. Uncheck the box for `Start only if the following network connection is available`

Since I did this, the refreshing that was occurring every second is no longer present, and the processor utilization is down for this process. Hopefully, this will help someone else.

Comment: Playing with security is a bad practice. Yes, Windows Defender is not reliable, but if `Antimalware Service Executable` suspiciously uses CPU a lot, the reason could be uncaught malware triggering such behavior or concurrent antivirus. Anyway, consider a full scan of computer using a reliable antivirus (not free-fakes).

Comment: That is good advice. This was a machine with a fresh, clean build that had not even touched the Internet aside from the usual sites that we always use (sites in a secure domain). We use a reputable enterprise version antivirus program. I don't know anyone who has ever relied on Windows Defender personally, though. I've found it to be more conflicting than helpful.